# Add Javascript function return value to output

Tags: javascript, function, output, return-value

I have the following code:

```
var Faculty180API = {
    token: '1a88be52b9e9dd649998c3c1979b6b5c79cc160e',
    base_url: 'https://www.faculty180.com/api.php',
    account: 'DemoLinks',
    last_results: null,

    fetch: function(path, params, callback) {
        $.ajax((this.base_url + this.make_path(path)), {
            data: this.make_params(params),
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            success: callback,
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(xhr) {
                if(xhr.status == 200) {
                    $('#results').text(xhr.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    $('#URL').text(Faculty180API.base_url . HERE);          
                    $('#results').text(xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText);  
                }
            }
        });
    },
    make_params: function(params){
        params['token'] = this.token;
        return $.param(params);
    },
}
```

In the line that I have written `HERE`, I want to add what `Function(params)` returns to the output. How can I do this?

Comment: What is this `Function(params)` you speak of? Do you mean that `make_params` function at the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but I'm thinking you can just call it like this:

```
$('#URL').text(Faculty180API.base_url + Faculty180API.make_params( yourParams ) );
```

Also note that I changed your . (after base_url) to a +. Dot is string concatenation in PHP; in Javascript it's +

Comment: Also, you have an extra comma after make_params function that should be deleted.